# Pass shell parameters as stdin to invoked program

Tags: bash, shell, eof

I'm trying to run a program with each of my script's arguments passed as a different line on stdin. My current attempt involves using a `for` loop, as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

[My Program] <<EOF
for i in "$@"
do
   $i
done

EOF
```

This doesn't work -- the program actually receives `for i in` as part of its input, instead of being given the list of arguments themselves. How would I change it to function?

Comment: What's this `run` command that (presumably) takes a script on its input? Where are you getting it from? Where's its documentation? If you want to defer the evaluations of the heredoc's contents you need to quote the sigil (`<<'EOF'` rather than `<<EOF`), but it's not clear how this would work even so.

Comment: If you just want to count arguments, `count=$#` and there you are. No loop needed, no heredoc, no nonexistent `run` command.

Comment: If you want to clarify a specific question here, please try to build a [mcve] -- the simplest possible code that generates your problem, with examples of input/invocation, intended output, and actual output.

Comment: The run is a program made with C. Actually, It doesn't matter. The problem is that I can't specify EOF state by using for state...

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780931/loop-inside-heredoc-in-shell-scripting

Comment: What do you mean by the words "EOF state"? What you create with `<<EOF` is called a *heredoc* -- but what do you mean by using the word "state" in combination? What are the actual contents you want to put on `run`'s stdin?

Comment: I've edited the question to be less confusing. Of course, that assumes that I interpreted it correctly -- if not, please roll the edit back and replace with similarly unambiguous text asking whatever you actually meant.

Comment: BTW, you could just run `printf '%s\n' "$@" | ./run` and skip the heredoc altogether.

Answer (score 1):

To feed your program's stdin a newline-separated list of the command-line arguments with which your script was called:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./your-program <<<"$(printf '%s\n' "$@")"
```

...or, with POSIX sh-compatible heredoc syntax:

```
#!/bin/sh
./your-program <<EOF
$(printf '%s\n' "$@")
EOF
```

If for some reason you *really* want to use a `for` loop, you can do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
./your-program <<EOF
$(for i; do
    echo "$i"
  done)
EOF
```

...though note that `printf` would be a preferable replacement to `echo` even here; to understand why, see the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: Does the program see anything different than with `./your-program "$@"`? I assume that the newlines in your solution are eliminated anyway during word-splitting of the `printf` result, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, inside a heredoc there is no word-splitting. And because this is *inside a heredoc*, the contents are on stdin, not on the command line (which AFAICT is what the OP was asking us how to do).