# Transfer multiple files on single sftp connection in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to transfer mutiple files on single sftp connection from a folder, where new files are continuously generating, through shell script.

I'm taking approach from this answer using `heredocs` but failed.

[Loop inside "heredoc" in shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780931/loop-inside-heredoc-in-shell-scripting)

Something like this below code

```
sftp -P 8922 <server> <<EOF
while [[ true ]]
do
   listOfFiles=$(ls -1)

   if [[ ! -z $listOfFiles ]]
   then
         put * /somedir
   fi
done
EOF
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can just do `put * /somedir`, you don't need the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sftp` is not a shell, it doesn't execute scripts like this.

You need to execute a script that prints all the `put` commands, and pipe it to `sftp`.

```
for i in *
do
    echo "put $i /somedir"
done | sftp -P 8922 <server>
```